# Multi-dimensional array with different datatypes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I need some help in VB.NET:
I have six arrays who all have the same length, but the elements of them have different datatypes (string and long). I need to create a multidimensional array or a jagged array which later will be copied to an Excel range at once.

Is this possible or can I only have elements of the same type in an array? Are there any other ways which I can use alternatively?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a multidimensional array containing two separate types. The solution is to create a class which contains the two variables you need.

For example,

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property MyString As String
    Public Property MyInteger As Integer
End Class
```

The following step is in the class where you want to create an array. You can define the following:

```
//...
Dim myFancyObjects as MyObject(3)
//...
```

You can access your properties by doing the following:

```
Integer testNumber = myFancyObjects(0).myInteger
String testString = myFancyObjects(0).myString
```

Comment: If I use a separate class, can I copy the whole class with all emelend (e.g. 10 columns with 200 elements each) into a 10x200 Excel Range? If I need a loop to get back the stored values than this way I can't use. How I can copy the values to the Excel Range?

Comment: You put this 'MyObject' class in an array. This array contains an object with 2 properties, it's an alternative than accessing a 2 dimensional array. But the 2 dimensions are replaced by 2 properties. So yes it's possible.

Comment: What do you mean with "copy it into an array"?

I created the class, the Properties with the Getter/Setter and made a variable in my main class of the type of the new class. How I can store values in each of the Properties and then copy them back to Excel?

Comment: You store them like: 
myFancyObjects(0).myInteger = 3
myFancyObjects(0).myString = "Hello world"

Comment: This is my example code now:
<code>
'Class to store the values
Public Class HTClass 
    Private Dim m_Arr_1() As Long
 Public Property Arr_1() As Long()
  Get
   Return m_Arr_1
  End Get
  Set
   m_Arr_1 = value
  End Set
 End Property
End Class


'Main Class
'...
Dim HT As New HTClass
For i as Integer = 1 to lastRow
    HT.Arr_1(i - 1 - CLng(offset)) = i
Next 

For i As Long = 1 To 10
    MsgBox(HT.Arr_1(i))
Next

</code>

But I get an error when I try to access the Property value in the last For-Loop. Declaring HTClass(3) as you suggested did not work and I got an compiler error.

Comment: can you modify your question with this code please? That's easier to read.